# Window cut pinching after bevel applied to windows edges

Tags: windows

I tried to search an answer to my question, but didn't find a solution so far, so looking for Your help.
I'm trying to create a modular sci-fi corridor.
As You see in the first screen shot - this is the topology resulted, when I cut window in the simple shape, and after apply bevel to window edges - there is some pinching arises as seen in other two screen shots.
What can I do to eliminate those pinching?
I want to keep it low poly - I need to transfer this item to Unity.
[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image]

Blender file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KkKK7gSejsb-GbL_0kJa2EZMsFYSdx2N/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this topology is better looking:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, moonbots! Its much better, however still some pinching there. Is there a way to get rid of that at all, if Increasing number of faces and vertex still an option?

Comment: I'm not sure about the pinching you're talking about, here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=GVoev1OP" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/GVoev1OP/)

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I didn't see additional support loop around beveled window edges.
Thanks a lot! I recreated now without pinches. 
You saved my day!

Comment: If You can, can You please make a screencast of the workflow, how did You achieve this? I did a lot of manual work there to make edges and vertices straight

Comment: I've edited, at the end (2 last pictures), as I was a bit lazy to work on the left part of the object, I just used a knife to create the additional edge loop, then GG to slide (E to make it parallel to its next edge, F to the opposite), then, as I still had artifacts, to make sure that everything was on the same axis, select vertices and press S Y 0

Comment: I always forget these simple things, like parallel to next edge, etc. Thanks a lot for Your help!